# Once-per-day authentication issue (500 error) on Azure Mobile Services via Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, azure, oauth

finding it hard to troubleshoot this issue in an iOS app I'm developing, appreciate any tips.

Once-per-day (on the first use) the app fails to authenticate to Azure Mobile Services (using the Azure Mobile Services framework for iOS; Azure service is configured for Facebook authentication), using a Facebook token generated by the Facebook SDK (with what appears to be a correctly configured FB App on their site). Subsequent usage/calls to Azure have no problem once the app is reloaded.

Given it's once-per-day I'm assuming it's a token expiry issue, but I can't figure out where! Occurs in both simulator and real iPhone, and with FB Dev test accounts and real FB accounts.

The auth process I've established in-app is:

**1. In the AppDelegate**

Establish a shared Azure Mobile Services client object e.g.

```
self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:AZURE_SERVICE_URL applicationKey:AZURE_SHARED_APPKEY];
```

**2. In the MasterViewController**

Open the active FBSession with basic permissions:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:{...}]
```

Once the FBSession is open, grab the FB token from the session:

```
NSString *fbToken = session.accessTokenData.accessToken;
NSDictionary *fbTokenDict = @{@"access_token": fbToken};
```

Attempt to authenticate to Azure Mobile Services using the FB token, via the shared client in the AppDelegate:

```
MSClient *client = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client];
[client loginWithProvider:@"facebook" token:fbTokenDict completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error) { ... }];
```

*(I plan to persist the Azure credentials in the keychain and only refresh when needed, but not until I've solved this issue. Right now it basically performs a re-auth every time which is fine for testing.)*

Assuming no errors returned from Azure, continue with loading the data from the Azure service using standard Azure SDK calls.

**Issue**

Only on the first launch (either simulator, or real device; test or real FB account) after a long wait (say 10-30seconds) Azure Mobile Services returns a 500 error code to the app (among a lot of IIS HTML). Subsequent launches of the app do not return the error, and respond with data at access speeds.

**Tried these so far**

- The Azure Mobile Services logs don't show any issues
- Attempting to use the MSFilter delegate methods on the Azure service objects to catch errors reveal persistent 401 response codes, but responding to them doesn't affect the above behaviour at all
- Following advice on other threads here, I've tried different combinations of FB App settings related to setting the App as Native/Desktop app and secret stored/not stored in app; with no luck

Any tips most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a member of the Mobile Services team.

For efficiency reasons, Mobile Services will shut down free tier services that are not actively receiving traffic. When a request is sent to a service that has been shutdown, it takes some time for it to start back up again. There is an issue that is affecting a small number of customers that causes that first request to return a 500 and we are actively working on a fix.

Until the fix is in place, the best way for you to resolve your problem is to scale your service up to the basic or standard tier. If it turns out you are already scaled up, please let me know as we have only seen this issue occur for customers in the free tier so far.

Comment: Ah-ha, thank you! I've just switched it up and will see how it goes over the next 24 hours.

Comment: Confirming that this solved the problem, hasn't reoccurred since - thanks!